# Magento 2 : Add Button to Order View

Tags: magento2, orders, packing-slip, custom-button

I want to add custom button to the order view, which should print the package slip.
How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you specify, you are looking for admin or frontend?

Comment: @L-Klmn Please, check my answer. I hope that'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement. I think following extension is full file your requirement.

> https://marketplace.magento.com/fooman-printorderpdf-m2.html

And yes, it's free extension.

Hope that'll help you.

Comment: @l-klmn Please, let me know it's working for you or not.